# Windows wsl time sync - windows services for linux time drifts rapidly from actual system time in windows 11

Tags: windows-services

I see there are former questions, but I see no definitive solutions (sorry).

I have install wsl2 on windows11 using the default Ubuntu install.  All is working pretty well.

But I am getting time sync errors, and when I check, the time in Linux is off by some random number.  (I remember seeing that someone thought the cause was 'sleep' - which works fine when Windows 11 resumes, but breaks when wls/Linux was asleep.

I am looking for a reliable time sync solution.  Several tools complain when the time is not correct.

I have created a cron job running this bash script, and I will monitor:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ntpdate time.windows.com

date >> ~/bin/timex.log
```

But, when I just ran it by hand, I found that the time had drifted almost a whole second in less than 20 minutes!  IME, this is a huge drift in such a short time.

Here is the exact output:
`21 Jan 12:17:39 ntpdate[1152]: step time server 168.61.215.74 offset +0.875743 sec`